# libspotify API: number of albums is different when browsing the same artist

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to use the existing example browse.c to get the number of albums of an artist by given an artist uri. The return value of **sp_artistbrowse_num_albums(browse)** is different every time when I run the command **browse spotify:artist:3fMbdgg4jU18AjLCKBhRSm**. Why?

Do I understand correctly that the callback **artistbrowse_complete_cb** is invoked once only when browsing is complete, but callback **metadata_updated** is invoked whenever metadata is updated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I understand correctly that the callback artistbrowse_complete_cb is invoked once only when browsing is complete, but callback metadata_updated is invoked whenever metadata is updated?

That's correct. As I've said before, `metadata_updated` means "some metadata has been updated somewhere", and there are more specific callbacks like `artistbrowse_complete_cb` for more targeted operations like artist browsing.

As to why it keeps changing — it's a bit odd as the number of albums for an artist doesn't normally oscillate much, but albums can be added and removed on a daily basis. It's best to just accept what you're told and keep your UI up-to-date.

Comment: The number of albums changes when I run the command "browse $artist_uri" every few seconds. So I wonder if something goes wrong.

Comment: I only added this line **printf("%d albums\n", sp_artistbrowse_num_albums(browse));** at the beginning of function **browse_artist_callback()** in file spshell/browse.c.

Comment: I mean your own application, not spshell. No matter your answer, my original answer still stands — the catalog changes all the time, so you need to trust what `sp_artistbrowse_num_albums` etc give you, even if it seems crazy at times (it's likely we're just experiencing backend issues)

Comment: It happens in my own application as well. Anyway, I will keep watching it. Thanks.